Why do all tasks related to test fail. such as compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
All tasks related to test fail when I run./gradlew installDebug.
I tried to change the jdk version and the gradle version, but nothing worked
compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac 
mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource
mergeExtDexDebugAndroidTest
mergeLibDexDebugAndroidTest
checkDebugAndroidTestDuplicateClasses
processDebugAndroidTestResources
processDebugAndroidTestManifest
mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs
compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin
dexBuilderDebugAndroidTest
installDebugAndroidTest

This is my version information
com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.7.3
gradle:8.11.1

dependencies：
dependencies {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation "org.imtp:common:$commonVersion"
    implementation project(':react-native-screens')
    implementation project(':react-native-safe-area-context')
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.6.1'

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}


Has anyone encountered this issue? It's been bothering me for several days.
